How do I create a screen-sized window without typing in the screen resolution (via Tkinter)?
I'm trying to make a transparent window with an image (ideally an animation) that will appear on the player's desktop outside the Ren'Py window, but I have a problem: the window doesn't appear if I don't write its resolution with numbers only, but I need it to be the player's screen's resolution (a variable);
Here's my code with comments:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
    
window = tk.Tk()
scr_width = window.winfo_width()
scr_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_resolution = str(scr_width)+"x"+str(scr_height)
    
    
window.overrideredirect(True) # hides the taskbar
    
window.geometry("1536x864") # only this works, but I need it to use the player's screen resolution
# window.geometry(screen_resolution) # window just doesn't appear!
# window.geometry("{}x{}".format(scr_width, scr_height)) # window doesn't appear as well

window.overrideredirect(True) # hides the taskbar
window.after(5000, lambda: window.destroy()) # closes the window after 10 seconds


transparent_color = '#abcdef'
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', transparent_color)

img = PhotoImage(file="my_path/my_img.png")
canvas = Label(window, image=img, relief="solid", width= 20, height= 8, anchor= CENTER, bg=transparent_color)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

window.mainloop()


Use window.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1) instead of window.geometry(...).

@acw1668, I'm not sure if I will be able to use screen width and screen height variables then, but thanks.

You can certainly set screen_resolution as a variable
For example setting screen_resolution = "1536x864" , will work.
However have you checked what your variables return (use a print statement)?
scr_width = window.winfo_width()
scr_height = window.winfo_height()
print(f"Screen Size: Width: {scr_width}, Height: {scr_height}")

I suspect that screen_resolution = str(scr_width) + "x" + str(scr_height) is '1 x 1' which is why you don't see anything
The following may give you better results but you may still not get the correct values. Read the link
scr_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
scr_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

Also with later releases of Python it's better to use f strings.
For creating your screen_resolution variable you can use;
screen_resolution = f"{scr_width}x{scr_height}"

And the line;
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(scr_width, scr_height)) 

can be written as;
window.geometry(f"{scr_width}x{scr_height}")


I cannot check the results because the window doesn't even show, unfortunately. And I don't know the player's screen resolution, this is why I tried winfo_screenwidth/height.

I cannot check the results because the window doesn't even show What does that mean? If you are talking about the print statement, it will show in the console, regardless of the window showing or not.

OK, I got it. Checked it without replacing window.geometry("1536x864") so it lounches normally, and it is 1. But how do I fix this? What did I do wrong? Edit: I added window.update_idletasks as people suggested, but now it returns "200, 200".

Did using winfo_screenwidth() & winfo_screenheight() rather than winfo_width() & winfo_height() also return incorrect values for screen size?  Did you you check the linked SO Post other suggestions.

Now it works, thank you very much! Sorry for being inattentive, I didn't notice the difference between these two functions.

window.info_screenwidth() should be used instead of just window.info_width()!
